# Не отображается сайт на Github Page

Tags: git, github, github-pages

Репозиторий: https://github.com/marinatn/marinatn.github.io
Сайт не по ссылке marinatn.github.io не отображается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать?

Comment: Неправда, всё отлично отображается https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApNav.png

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Смотрите тут инфу по деплою: https://github.com/marinatn/marinatn.github.io/deployments/activity_log?environment=github-pages Кст, github-pages запускается на серверах гитхаба без явного указания сервера, а то, что у вас там php-код торчит ничего не даст, т.к. тут скорее как статичный сайт. Поэтому, если открыть сайт https://marinatn.github.io/ там будут куски php кода

Answer (score 0):

1. На GH Pages могут хоститься **только статичные сайты** - никакой динамики, никакого PHP. Учите матчасть
2. Код, даже в мелочах, надо писать правильно, чтобы не искать потом "откуда странности", а даже [тут](https://github.com/marinatn/marinatn.github.io/blob/index/index.html) я этого не наблюдаю, в первых строках и в последней

Итог - писать код явно не ваше, займитесь чем-то более жизненным... букварь там по верстке почитать, что ли